# Convert ' and " inside a string to be used inside a variable. (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

can someone help me with this please. I need to get this stored in a variable as a long string. I have a function called that simple inserts this into the DOM appended to another div. Everything works perfectly fine except I cant work out how to store this string with all the 's and "s inside it. I have tried using \ and unescape methods i have found in my search but cant seem to get anything to work. Can anyone help me out please?

```
'<div class="centerContent"><P>Please fill in the form below to send an email to H.O.V.A.R.<br/>All fields are required.</p><?php if(!empty($errors)): ?><div class="errorPanel"><ul><li><?php echo implode('</li><li>',$errors); ?></li></ul></div><?php endif ?><form action="contact.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8"><label>Your Name:<input type="text" name="name" style="display:block" autocomplete="off"<?php echo isset($fields['name']) ? 'value="' . e($fields['name']) . '"' : '' ?>></label><label>Your email address:<input type="text" name="email" style="display:block" autocomplete="off"<?php echo isset($fields['email']) ? 'value="' . e($fields['email']) . '"' : '' ?>></label><label>Your Message:<textarea name="message" rows="10" style="display:block"><?php echo isset($fields['message']) ? e($fields['message']) : '' ?></textarea></label><input type="submit" value="Send" style="display:block"></form></div>'
```

Comment: How on Earth is that string meant to be used? You have PHP tags inside it... are you using another language to parse PHP which will then render HTML?

Comment: @Shomz, Why cant he have php tags in that string if he is writing his JS in **.php** page ?

Comment: @RayonDabre In that case, it's irrelevant for the question as we only care for the final rendered string, right? I assume the quote problem comes from something like `var str = '<?= $phpString ?>';` in which case you **cannot** parse the PHP tags inside it.

Comment: Yeah true, except the string whic will be added after php execution, string looks good to me...

Comment: If the string is added after PHP execution, it won't get parsed by PHP.

Comment: @Shomz, Thats what..Php processed string would make more sence..

Answer (score 0):

Although the following shows how to escape quotes, having such a long string is quite unwieldy and it's unclear what you are trying to ultimately achieve...

Also, as you are also attempting to insert content from PHP, this will also need to be escaped in a similar fashion.

```js
var HTML = "<div class=\"centerContent\"><P>Please fill in the form below to send an email to H.O.V.A.R.<br/>All fields are required.</p><?php if(!empty($errors)): ?><div class=\"errorPanel\"><ul><li><?php echo implode('</li><li>',$errors); ?></li></ul></div><?php endif ?><form action=\"contact.php\" method=\"post\" accept-charset=\"utf-8\"><label>Your Name:<input type=\"text\" name=\"name\" style=\"display:block\" autocomplete=\"off\"<?php echo isset($fields['name']) ? 'value=\"' . e($fields['name']) . '\"' : '' ?>></label><label>Your email address:<input type=\"text\" name=\"email\" style=\"display:block\" autocomplete=\"off\"<?php echo isset($fields['email']) ? 'value=\"' . e($fields['email']) . '\"' : '' ?>></label><label>Your Message:<textarea name=\"message\" rows=\"10\" style=\"display:block\"><?php echo isset($fields['message']) ? e($fields['message']) : '' ?></textarea></label><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Send\" style=\"display:block\"></form></div>";

console.log(HTML);
```

Comment: Sorry, I have an index.php file which has <div id="whatever"></div> in it. Then a function in a linked js file populates the div, rather than having masses and masses of block code in the index file so its easier to read. 

As i said, everything works fine with another example, as there are no characters that are interfering with the HTML tags and what not.... 

I simply want to convert the above string into a string that can be passed into a var that shows as html and processes as it would if it were all just written inside the <div id=whatever>,,,code inserted in here....</div>

Comment: What does the -1 next to my comment mean? did i do something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Since your string starts with single quote, you need to escape every single quote during the time you are building the string (if you were starting the string with double quote you had to escape the double qotes). I.e inside the string every single quote needs to be escaped by a back-slash in front of it (like so: \'). You cannot do this when using the string, since PHP and/or Javascript will complain about the string having illegal tokens.

When you do so, you can echo it in PHP, but since it is a string it will not give you the result you wanted. You'll either get a distorted form or an error depending on the technique used.

This all boils down to having PHP calls in the string. What you therefor should do is eliminating the php calls in your string. So insted of entering "`<?php .... ?>`" in the string you should enter the outcome of the PHP call into the string.